# Store customized date in database

Tags: java, mysql

I have an application which is used by all over world. But the application server is present in India.

One of my application features is 
**create template using date 
So, for that I have to store the client systems date & time.
But I need to store date time based on Client side or server side in single column in database?

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Do you have the clients locale/timezone? If so apply it to the date while storing and retrieving

Comment: Store GMT date/time, and convert to local time on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few options here, depending on how you wish to delegate responsibility and how the templates will be used.

The simplest solution is simply that the client submits the date & time and you store it as is with no time zone information. This however assumes that the template would only be used in the same time zone, or that it is acceptable to have the same date & time visible everywhere according to where it was created (probably not the best approach for a worldwide system)!

Another option is that you store the value as UTC.  Then you can either:

- Make the client responsible for converting to their local time
  zone
- Store the offset / time zone separately and include it in the result

This is probably the best approach

Or another option is to store the date & time together with the time zone it was created within.  Then you might have to convert between different time zones either on the server or client side if you need a different one.